# Convert custom powershell object to XML file

Tags: xml, powershell, save

```
$cominfo = [pscustomobject]@{

                    HostID         = $Computer

                    prodinfo     = $DisplayName

                    version      = $Version

                    InstallDate     = $Date

                    Producer       = $Publisher

                    UninstallString = $UninstallString

                    InstallLocation = $InstallLocation

                    InstallSource   = $InstallSource

                    HelpLink        = $HelLink

                    EstimatedSizeMB = [decimal]([math]::Round(($thisSubKey.GetValue('EstimatedSize') * 1024) / 1MB, 2))

                  } 

                  if(Test-Path -path '.\AssetManagement.xml'){
                    $xml = import-clixml -Path '.\AssetManagement.xml'  
                  }
                  $xml += $cominfo | select *
                  Export-Clixml -Path '.\AssetManagement.xml' -InputObject $xml

                  $cominfo.pstypenames.insert(0, 'System.Software.Inventory')

                  Write-Output $cominfo
```

The code snip above shows the custom object components and the subsequent attempt to convert to XML and save/append to an existing XML file (if the file exists) In particular,

```
  if(Test-Path -path '.\AssetManagement.xml'){
                    $xml = import-clixml -Path '.\AssetManagement.xml'  
                  }
                  $xml += $cominfo | select *
                  Export-Clixml -Path '.\AssetManagement.xml' -InputObject $xml
```

Is a snip of the code that I have been having trouble with. I am by no means a powershell expert, and this is for my personal home asset management. I tried several variants I found on the web, this snippet being the last, and none have accomplished the goal.

All methods I have tried from searching here and google have not produced a single XML file as I expect, but I always get the output displayed as expected. I was hoping someone here can help me output each custom object to an xml file (create file if necessary, append to existing otherwise), not just to the display prompt.

I did try things like "Testing testing one two 3" | export-clixml '.\testing.xml' and those commands work as intended, so I know my system should allow the writing of these files to the current directory, just not sure why its not working for that custom powershell object output.......

Comment: See `convertto-xml -?`

Comment: Also, see Export-CliXml.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try doing

```
$comInfoObj | Export-Clixml comInfoObj.xml
```

Does it create the file comInfoObj.xml or give an error?